# Why isn't multi-touch working for my imagebuttons?

Tags: android

I'm using imagebuttons that play sounds using SoundPool. Here is example code of one of the imagebuttons:

ImageButton Button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sound);
        Button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(1);
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

For some reason, it doesn't allow you to click multiple buttons at the same time. Is it because I'm building for 1.6 SDK?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, if it isn't obvious from the code, each one of my imagebuttons has an onTouchListener(). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

why aren't you using onClickListener??????

```
    ImageButton t = new ImageButton(this);
    t.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```